# Complete WordPress custom post type category tree

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I have post type called 'sisallot', which has 5 subcategories. Lets call these subcats s1,s2,s3,s4,s5. 
Every subcategory has a couple of subcategories (these would then be ss1,ss2..etc.) and these ssubcategories has the final posts to get.

I've added first level subcategories to my navbar.

**The question is:**

How can I create such category.php -template loop that loops subcategories(ss1,ss2,ss3..etc.) and their titles and excerpts, of its parent category ( s1,s2,s3...etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Use that child_of parameter to list only categories that are children of one parent.

Comment: Be sure to also use the 'taxonomy' parameter if your categories are a custom taxonomy ;)

Comment: Thanks for that MilanG. That got me started. The complete solution was to create two foreach -loops: First gets the child cats and the inner gets the real posts. Not sure if this is a smart solution though.